# Single-words for at-least and at-most

Tags: single-word-requests

While naming each operator in a programming language, the comparison operators came up, and there's no obvious name for two of them.

- `=`  Equality Operator
- `≠`  Inequality Operator
- `>`  Superiority Operator
- `<`  Inferiority Operator
- `≥`  ??
- `≤`  ??

The `≥` operator is usually named *greater-than-or-equal-to*, *not-less-than* or *at-least*.

The `≤` operator is usually named *less-than-or-equal-to*,  *not-greater-than* or *at-most*.

The `>` operator is normally just named *greater-than*, so *superior* seemed like an obvious, single-word alternative. Likewise, *inferior* seems like a good alternative to *less-than*.

For the remaining two, I thought of using neologisms, and came up with *asuperior*  for `≤` and *ainferior* for `≥`. While, *asuperior* works pretty well, *ainferior* doesn't feel as natural or intuitive.

Are there single-word names that make sense for all six operators?

Comment: *Floor* and *Ceiling* correspond to the minimum and the maximum respectively, but in English are neither verbs nor comparatives, and in most programming languages where they *are* verbs (functions) they return one of the )arguments, instead of a Boolean truth value. In [my favorite programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/j), for example, ≤ is spelled `<:` and *floor* is spelled `<.` (resp. `>:` and `>.` for ≥ and *ceiling*).

Comment: Consider *minimal(ly)* for `≥` and *maximal(ly)* for `≤`. They're clunky if you need to call them *M... Operator*, though.

Comment: **Tops** *informal, adverb* at the most. *"some civil servant earning twenty-eight thousand a year, tops"* [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/top)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is no single word for ≥ "greater than or equal to" or ≤ "less than or equal to".

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater-than_sign
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less-than_sign
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1):

[Some programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Standard_relational_operators), notably classic Fortran and Bash scripting, use the following two-letter names for the six operators.

- = **EQ**
- ≠ **NE**
- > **GT**
- < **LT**
- ≥ **GE**
- ≤ **LE**